# preventing multi refresh to count on stats script

Tags: php

i am working on a project which one of our web application would be somehow JavaScript code to gather **statistical information about visitors** but as far as i know on server side PHP application i should somehow handle the code in a way that multi refresh doesn't count and counting on IP based is not a good idea since many users may have the same IP , cookie or session are also vulnerable to this issue because cookie manager can just wipe out all the cookie related to the site so PHP won't recognize the user and count it new,timeframe jobs and all other way to get-around of this issue are also as far as i know based on cookie or session or ip or a mixture of ip/referrer and all other available data from header, how can i handle it and get more reliable data from users and don't permit them to create fake stats. as i believe there must be a way (i hope so)...!?

Comment: IP, session and cookies (header data) is all the data you can get from a user and they all can be deleted or faked. its end-user privacy and they have access over it

Comment: Use `localStorage` in javascript (before you invoke PHP code with ajax....). On first time u fill `localStorage` and after u verify if `localStorage` has old data => do nothing

Comment: To add onto @MohdMoe's point, referrer data (as you suggested using) can also be faked. Your best bet is to use session data if you trust your users not to fake statistics, or track IPs if you don't.

Comment: True, as you pointed above also that many users could be on the same IP, but they wont (must not) have the same encrypted key in the cookie, you can use a fingerprint (create a hash using IP,USER-AGENT,SESSION KEY) to identify each user, but still it can be removed by the end of user's session if he removes the cookie

Comment: @Fess localstorage can also be manipulated by the user

Comment: local storage using chrome developer tools can be easily manipulated or firebug in ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think cookies would be ideal for this kind of problem, but if you do not want to use that then you've got yourself a tough cookie. Unfortunately you don't have many other options since HTTP is stateless.

I would use session vars in this case since the user cannot meddle with the data saved there. There is however the risk of session hijacking, but if your site is open to that vulnerability you need to look at securing the site on a more global level that just the hit counter. The session variable is bound to your site since the data in it is saved on the server rather than in the users browser. And is bound to your user since it saves a cookie with a key in the users browser to request the data from the server.

Here is an example on how you can implement this and not worry about deleting other sessions on the site.

```
<?php
function hit_counter() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['hit_counter'])) { // Check if the user has the hit_counter session
        if(isset($_SESSION['hit_counter']['time']) && isset($_SESSION['hit_counter']['page'])) { // Check if the user has the time and the page set from the last visit
            $last_time = $_SESSION['hit_counter']['time'];
            $last_page = $_SESSION['hit_counter']['page'];

            $now = time(); // The current UNIX time stamp in seconds
            $current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // The page name

            /*
                If the users hasn't requested this page
                in the last 10 seconds or if the user 
                comes from another page increment the 
                hit counter
            */
            if(($now - $last_time) > 10 || $last_page != $current_page) {
                /* INCREMENT YOUR HIT COUNTER HERE */
            }
        }

        unset($_SESSION['hit_counter']); // Delete this hit counter session
    }

    // And create a new hit counter session
    $_SESSION['hit_counter'] = array();
    $_SESSION['hit_counter']['time'] = time();
    $_SESSION['hit_counter']['page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
?>
```

You will never touch any of the other session variables since you're only `unset()`ing the hit counter variable. There is no need for you to handle `session_destroy()`, but you need to make sure that there is a `session_start()` in the beginning of every page you would like to use function in.

You could edit the script to not factor in time if you'd only want to count hits if the user comes from another page on your site.

This is as far as I can see, a hit counter with a sensible level of security for most sites. Or at the very least a good start.

Some more information about [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Comment: so there are no other way,  ill try considering session way in my application and see how far i can get
thanks for code sample by the way

Comment: Unfortunately, since HTTP is stateless(that is every request is new and unique). There is no other way to know who the request is coming from. And you're welcome :)

Comment: You could as an added measure of security add a field in the session var where you save a unique hash created based on user information e.g. `<?php $_SESSION['hit_counter']['user_hash'] = sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>`. You could add more data to the hash to make it even more unique.

Comment: uniqueness is not all the thing , as our data even session (session handle its session id in a cookie so it can be deleted and then there is no session so new session new user) all i can do as i thought before is somehow hardening the process as you said in sample and comment sample , but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I created this

```php
<?php

namespace Codelaby\EventDateGenerator;

class CounterVisitors
{
    private $filename = "counter.txt";
    private $sessionId;
    private $sessionStart;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionId'])) {
            $this->sessionId = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $_SESSION['sessionId'] = $this->sessionId;
            $this->sessionStart = time();
            $this->hitCounter();
        } else {
            $this->sessionId = $_SESSION['sessionId'];
            if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionStart'])) {
                $this->sessionStart = time();
            } else {
                $this->sessionStart = $_SESSION['sessionStart'];
            }
            if (time() - $this->sessionStart > 60) {
                $this->sessionStart = time();
                $this->hitCounter();
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['sessionStart'] = $this->sessionStart;
    }

    private function saveCounter($counter = 0)
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
            touch($this->filename);
        }
        $fp = fopen($this->filename, "w");
        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            return;
        }
        fwrite($fp, $counter);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    public function readCounter()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
            touch($this->filename);
        }
        $fp = fopen($this->filename, "r");
        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            return;
        }
        $file_size = filesize($this->filename);
        if ($file_size <= 0) {
            $counter = 0;
        } else {
            $counter = intval(fread($fp, $file_size));
        }
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        return $counter;
    }

    public function hitCounter()
    {
        $counter = $this->readCounter();
        $counter++;
        $this->saveCounter($counter);
        return $counter;
    }

    public function resetCounter($counter = 0)
    {
        $this->saveCounter(0);
    }
}
```

How to use

```php
session_start() //before send headers

$counterVisitors = new CounterVisitors();
$visitors = $counterVisitors->readCounter();

echo 'visitors: ' . $visitors;
```

The script generate counter.txt if not exist, only increment visit if user start new session or wait 60 seconds for refresh